# SQL Server connection string question

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a named SQL instance on the server.
There is already default instance of SQL Server 2005 and a newly named one - SQL Server 2008. I'm using the "Network library" property to use TCP connection but for some reason, he try's to connect the default instance and omit an error about login error.

If I remove the network library propery the connection established as well without any error.

I'm using windows authntication and have all the permissions needed.

The problematic connection string:

***Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName,1433;network library=dbmssocn;Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;Integrated security=SSPI***

The working connection string:

***Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;Integrated security=SSPI***

Omitting the ***,1433;network library=dbmssocn*** from the connection string makes the difference. adding it maked the server to connect the deafult instance.
Both of the server allows remote connections.

I would like to understand why, please.
Thanks in advance,

Tamir

Comment: You have also removed the port number from the working connection string, that port number is the default port which the default instance will be listening on

Comment: Yes, thank you, i did removed it also :), sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: BTW, this is this might be more appropriate for serverfault.com

Comment: Already on serverfault too http://serverfault.com/questions/104922

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from my answer on [your question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/104922)...

The connection strings have 2 differences so I'll try to answer for this...

- Named instances do not listen on port 1433 (only the default instance by, er, default)
- The instance name is ignored when the port is specified

So:

- `ServerName\InstanceName,1433` means connect to server "ServerName" on port 1433
- `ServerName\InstanceName` means connect to server "ServerName" and resolve instance name to correct port (resolve uses port 1434 UDP)

However, `network library=dbmssocn` means use tcp. It could be the SQL Server instance (see port stuff) does not listen on tcp

Answer (score 1):

At a guess the 2005 and 2008 instances would be listening on different ports.  Perhaps you need to set the connection string for the SQL Server 2008 instance to the correct port; you could be hitting the SQL Server 2005 listener and asking it for an instance that is not present on the 2005 installation.

What port is the SQL Server 2008 instance listening on - [This article discusses the subject.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3764516/Discover-SQL-Server-TCP-Port.htm) and has a powershell script that actually interrogates the system to find out what port the DBMS is really listening on.  It also talks a little about where this config lives in the registry.